# sshd is getting down frequently

Tags: rhel, sshd

I'm using an RHEL 7.4 server for my development purposes. The issue is sshd is getting down frequently after sometime without any error, checked the logs for any clues, but no luck so far. 
Any help appreciated..! Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! You might have better luck with this question over at serverfault.com, which is another Stack Exchange site that focusses more on server admin and OS-related problems.

Comment: It's unfortunately unclear what `sshd is getting down frequently` effectively means: Is the daemon still available but doesn't accept new SSH connections or is the daemon itself gone? And what does `systemctl status sshd.service -l` say if you experience a "down"?

Comment: Hi @rsc, The deamon service will be down and systemctl status sshd -l - gives me that the deamon is not active and nothing else. But i'm able to connect to the VM using RDSH.